# Allow button in system preferences not present - macpro 5.1 macOS Sierra 10.13.6 - Line 6 pod 3 Live Driver Issue

Tags: macos, preferences

I m trying to install some drivers, (Line6 / Digidesign nd Zoom ) .
These drivers (all latest versions that works with Sierra) are not working and my devices (mainly audio units) are obviously not recognised .
I read everywhere that the solution is goin to System Preference then Security nd Privacy and then on General window click on Allow button .
The problem is that There isn't that button .
I attach the pic to show it .

[image: allow button??]

Comment: There is no "Allow" button.  It sounds like the instructions are incorrect.  Can you post a link to them or take a screenshot of of portion that tells you to do this?

Comment: Same happens to me, any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The allow button dynamically appears when you try to install and use for example 3rd party kernel extensions.

Re-run the installer for the drivers for the hardware, and revisit Security & Privacy in System Preferences. It should show up then.

Comment: Sometimes it still doesn't show up. Have not been able to figure out why that happens.

Comment: I have the same problem. In my case it's Virtualbox. The "Allow" button never appears, no matter how many times I re-install, with varying steps.